# The meaning of 一時期繁く

Tags: translation, words

I've been reading a book and met a phrase I don't understand. 
I have translated it like that:

一時期繁く通った程度のことらしいが、そこに居を定める人間に出会ってみると、懐かしくなったものとみえる。

It seems to a degree of being there for one hour frequently, but when it comes to meeting the human being who lives there, it seems to be nostalgic.

But what I'm not sure about is the [一時期繁く] part. What exactly frequency is that? Is it translated as "every one hour"?

Comment: That is two separate words, 一時期 and 繁く.

Comment: I think 一時期 doesn't mean "one hour", but "for some time (in the past)". That'd also fit 通う better, as it means "go there" rather than "be there".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I think I understand better now.